# Find a general form for the l.t. $f:\mathbb{R}_2 [X]\to \mathbb{R}^2, f(X^2+X-1)=(1,2),f(2X+3)=(-1,1),f(X^2-X-4)=(2,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If we take the base $\{X^2,X,1\}$ then we have an equivalent $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined over $\{(1,1,-1),(0,2,3),(1,-1,-4)\}$, which is not an l.i. set. We want to find a general expression for any $(x,y,z)$, so we want to solve for $a,b,c$:

$$(x,y,z)=a(1,1,-1)+b(0,2,3)+c(1,-1,-4) \iff \\ a=x-c.b=-x/2+y/2+c,z=-5/2x-3/2y$$

For any $c\in\mathbb{R}$. we have

$$f(x,y,z)=f((x-c)(1,1,-1)+(-x/2+y/2+c)(0,2,3)+c(1,-1,-4))=(3/2x-1/2y,3/2x+1/2y)$$

Is this it? Or does this equation only work for (x,y,z) such that $z=-5/2x-3/2y$? What does it mean then than $z=-5/2x-3/2y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow what you did.

Since you want a linear transformation from a $3$-dimensional  space to a $2$-dimensional one, it can be represented by a $2×3$ matrix.

You don't have a basis for $\Bbb R_2[x]$, so it isn't uniquely determined.   Add $1$  to the first two vectors. Then you will have a basis.  You are free to choose $f(1)=(a,b)$.  This will determine  a linear $f$.

To put it in the standard basis,  use the appropriate change of basis matrix.